# LESS CSS background with relative path

Tags: css, less

I'm facing with a problem when using LESS as stylesheet for my website. Personally, I'd rather use relative path in CSS than an absolute path (only my habit), but now when I use LESS with importing feature, I have a problem as the following demonstrates.

I have a `main.less` file in root folder

```
@import "inc/inc.less";
```

and a file `inc.less` in folder `inc`

```
.homeBgr {  
    background: url('icons/Home.gif');
}
```

the image `Home.gif` is in folder `/root/inc/icons`

```
 - main.less
      - inc
         - inc.less
         - icons
            - Home.gif
```

with `lessc` output is

```
.homeBgr {  
    background: url('icons/Home.gif');
}
```

However, my expectation is

```
.homeBgr {  
   background: url('inc/icons/Home.gif');
}
```

If I use less.js as client compiler, I got the output as expected, however If I use `lessc`, I do not.

Has anyone had the same problem, and has a solution for this? Or really, any suggestions on how to get this working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

you have to use .less 's escaping feature.  It will look something like this.  firebug it or use chromes firebug like thing to check the path if this doesn't work and you need to adjust it to a root folder.  you can at least adjust it after its escaped though.

```
background: ~"url('inc/icons/Home.gif')";
```

Comment: I think this way make me or customer confuses when take a look on the `inc.less` file because the relative path is not meaning (not relate to `inc.less` file)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having main.less in root and other less files in /inc, put all of your less files into a "css", "styles", or "less" folder.  Then you can use a consistent relative path to images by doing "../icons/home.gif"

Answer (score 1):

The relative image path relates to the generated CSS file, not to the LESS file.