# chrome cannot load local images that configured in less file

Tags: javascript, css, less

I write a less file like below:(footer.less)

```
.phoneIcon {
  display: table-cell;
  background: url('../assets/footer_tel.png') no-repeat;
}
```

but when I deploy in k8s, it cannot show in chrome, when I debug it , I found that the chrome searching this image in this path:

```
Request URL: https://assets/footer_logo.png
```

why this happen? and In element I found here the url is changed to :
[image]

can anyone help me ,thanks

Comment: or add a base href tag in your dom with the HTTP HOST ^^

Comment: try set `background-position: 100% 100%;`

Comment: @לבנימלכה tried, but not work.

Comment: @episch , a dom? how? I load footer.less in a js file.thanks

Comment: add you full url like:`url('https://yoursite/assets/footer_tel.png')`

Comment: @לבנימלכה  no, I can just use relative path in this code

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694990/less-css-background-with-relative-path